# what is wrong with this ruby inheritance code?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

```
 class Song

   def initialize(name,artist,duration)
    @name=name
    @artist=artist
    @duration=duration
   end

   def to_s
    "Song: #{@name}--#{@artist} (#{@duration})"
   end

 end 

 class KarokeSong < Song

   def intialize(name,artist,duration,lyrics)
     super(name,artist,duration)
     @lyrics=lyrics
   end

 end

 aSong=KarokeSong.new("Umerilla ila ila ila a","Rihanna",260,"my lyrics")

 puts aSong.to_so
```

$I have named this file as jukebox.rb i am using ruby version 2.0.0 p451 and when i try to run this example, the ruby interpreter issues the following error

> Wrong number of arguments (4 of 3) (Arguments error)
>
> > from jukebox.rb:20:in 'new'
> >
> > > from jukebox.rb:20:in 'main'

Comment: Well, when doing KarokeSong.new you are calling initialize from Song which only expects 3 arguments.

Comment: Your class name is probably also spelled wrong - it should be called KaraokeSong instead of Karokesong (you're missing an 'a').

Comment: i got it solved , @Michael Rapadas pointed out the mis spelled method name initalize instead of initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KarokeSong's `initialize` method is spelled wrong.

Comment: oh my bad that was a very silly mistake.thank you